# Add elements to a List while iterating over it. (Java)

Tags: java, listiterator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: adding elements to a collection during iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993025/java-adding-elements-to-a-collection-during-iteration)

My problem is that I want to expand a list with new elements while iterating over it and I want the iterator to continue with the elements that I just added.

From my understanding the `ListIterator.add()` adds an element before the current element in the list, not after it. Is it possible to achieve this in some other way?

Comment: You can use ListLterator for modifying list during iterating,it provides more functionality than iterator.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can't modify a Collection while iterating over it using an `Iterator`, except for `Iterator.remove()`.

However, if you use the [`listIterator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#listIterator%28%29) method, which returns a `ListIterator`, and iterate over that you have more options to modify. From the javadoc for `add()`:

> The new element is inserted before the implicit cursor: ... a subsequent call to `previous()` would return the new element

Given that, this code should work to set the new element as the next in the iteration:

```
ListIterator<T> i;
i.add(e);
i.previous(); // returns e
i.previous(); // returns element before e, and e will be next
```

This will work except when the list starts iteration empty, in which case there will be no previous element. If that's a problem, you'll have to maintain a flag of some sort to indicate this edge case.

Answer (score 16):

There might be some trick with ListIterator, but the easiest solution is probably an old style index loop. Verify performance isn't an issue (no linked lists - but ArrayList is fine).

```
List<Object> myList;

for(int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++)
{
  Object current = myList.get(i); 
  // Anything you insert after i will be discovered during next iterations
}
```

Comment: Yep. This not only solves the problem unambiguously, but avoids the gotchas of not knowing how an iterator is going to act. I like it!

Comment: hmm. if you add a element into list here, you get infinity loop: myList.add(current + "one more");

Comment: @yaroslavTir yes? Obviously you need to make sure there is an end condition (like with any recursive code or queue processing).

Comment: Isn't it O(n^2)? As we have a loop (O(n)) and inside of it we also retrieving element from any position (also O(n))

Comment: @Anton absolutely. On your average list where n is < 100 (or even 1000), it probably won't matter and getting simpler easier to read code is a better solution than convoluted optimized code. (Or not, it depends - but premature optimization is the root of all evil)

Answer (score 9):

How about

```
List<Foo> fooList = getFooList();
List<Foo> tempFooList = new ArrayList<Foo>()


for(Foo f : fooList)
{
   ...
   // add items that need to be added to temp
   tempFooList.add(new Foo());
   ...
}

fooList.addAll(tempFooList);
```