# Is it not safe to insert into a list while iterating through it?

Tags: java, concurrency

Is it true that it is not safe to insert into a list while iterating through it? Thoughts? I'm not sure personally...

Comment: "A list" is not all that helpful.  Some lists may be "safe" to use in such a way, others may not.  "Safe" is not particularly well defined either!

Comment: I think it will throw an concurrentmodification exception if you modify the list directly

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7409771/2024761)

Comment: @Affe It's not possible without the iterator right? Apart from that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I expected it throw ConcurrentModificationException.
I test it on simple example:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(3);
        for(Iterator<Integer> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();it.next()){
            System.out.println(it.toString());
            list.add(4);
        }
    }
}
```

changen ArrayList to LinkedList give the same result.
If I remember exactly only remove operation are valid

Answer (score 1):

If you are iterating through a collection using an `Iterator` object, then changing the underlying collection will create a `ConcurrentModificationError` that will crash the code. This applies even if you are using a for-each loop, because this type of loop implicitly declares an `Iterator`.

[More information on ConcurrentModificationException.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html)