# Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, arrays, iterator, hashset

When I run the below code, I get an exception. I searched but couldn't find any solution.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
     at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(Unknown Source)
     at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
     at com.aybits.software.linkgrabber.Grabber.main(Grabber.java:45)
```

Line number 45 is *for(String linkFromCollection : linksList){*

```
public class Grabber {

static String url;
Document doc;
static Set<String> linksList = new HashSet<String>();
String matchingString ="java2s.com/Code";
static boolean isCrawling = true;
static int STOP_WATCH = 0;

public Grabber(String url){
    Grabber.url = url;
}

public void grabLinks(String urlToCrawl) throws IOException{
    doc = Jsoup.connect(urlToCrawl).timeout(20 * 1000).get();
    Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");

    for (Element link : links) {
        //print(" * a: <%s>  (%s)", link.attr("abs:href"), trim(link.text(), 35));
        if(link.attr("abs:href").toString().contains(matchingString)){
            if(!linksList.contains(link.attr("abs:href").toString())){
                System.out.println("Added - " + link.attr("abs:href"));
                linksList.add(link.attr("abs:href").toString());
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Grabber app = new Grabber("http://java2s.com");
    app.grabLinks(url);

    while(isCrawling){
        for(String linkFromCollection : linksList){
            app.grabLinks(linkFromCollection);

            if(linksList.contains(linkFromCollection)){
                STOP_WATCH += 5;
                System.out.println("STOP_WATCH IS " + STOP_WATCH);
            }else{
                STOP_WATCH -= 1;
                System.out.println("STOP_WATCH IS " + STOP_WATCH);
            }

            if(STOP_WATCH >= 100){
                isCrawling = false;
                System.out.println("STOP_WATCH IS " + STOP_WATCH);
            }
        }


    }
    ICVSWrite writer = new ICVSWrite();

    String[] strArray = (String[]) linksList.toArray();
    writer.write(strArray);

}

}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The line

```
linksList.add(link.attr("abs:href").toString());
```

modifies the `linksList` collection while you are iterating over it.  The next time through the `for` loop in `main`, Java calls `next` on the collection, sees that the collection has been modified, and throws the exception.

When you are doing an enhanced `for` loop, you cannot add to or remove from the collection.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot call `add` on a `Collection` while looping over it. Here:

```
for (Element link : links) {        
    if(...){
        if(...){
            ...
            linksList.add(link.attr("abs:href").toString());
                      ^^^ <- here
        }
    }
}
```

You call `grabLinks` method from your `main` method from within a loop over `linksList`:

```
for(String linkFromCollection : linksList) {
   app.grabLinks(linkFromCollection);
```

You have to add your items to another `Collection` and then copy them over after.

What had me puzzled for a little while was why the exception was coming from a `HashMap` as I had assumed that `linksList` was a `List` - *obviously* it's a `Set`. Not the best name in the world.

[This should help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7409763/2071828).