# How I can add objects into an ArrayList when I'm using this ArrayList in a for loop?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, loops, arraylist

I need to add some objects to an ArrayList that I am using in a for loop. This is the code:

```
        List<Bulto> bultosHijos = bultoDAO.findChilds(idBulto);
        List<Bulto> bultosMasProfundos = new ArrayList();

        for (Bulto bulto : bultosHijos) {
            List<Bulto> bultosNietos = bultoDAO.findChilds(bulto.getIdBulto());

            if (!bultosNietos.isEmpty()) {
                bultosHijos.addAll(bultosHijos.size(), bultosNietos);
            } else {
                bultosMasProfundos.add(bulto);
            }
        }
```

This is throwing me an "Current Modification Exception". I try changing the type that return my DAO, but I can not. How can I avoid this error and do this?

Thank's a lot

**EDIT 1:**

Thanks for all your replies! I am using now ListIterator and with the code below, works well! 
But if I do not use `listIterator.previous()` the while loop exits immediatly and I do not want this. Is ok?

```
        List<Bulto> bultosHijos = bultoDAO.findChilds(idBulto);
        List<Bulto> bultosMasProfundos = new ArrayList();
        ListIterator<Bulto> listIterator = bultosHijos.listIterator();

        while (listIterator.hasNext()) {
            Bulto bulto = listIterator.next();
            List<Bulto> bultosNietos = bultoDAO.findChilds(bulto.getIdBulto());

            if (!bultosNietos.isEmpty()) {
                for (Bulto bultoNieto : bultosNietos) {
                    listIterator.add(bultoNieto);
                    listIterator.previous();
                }
            } else {
                bultosMasProfundos.add(bulto);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You can use `ListIterator` to iterate.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409740/add-elements-to-a-list-while-iterating-over-it-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [ListIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) to add or remove concurrently while iterating arrayList. When you try to add or remove a object from a list by using forloop it will surely throws the `Current Modification Exception`. So you can't modify the list. By using `ListIterator` you can `add remove` object from the list.

Here is sample code:

```
List<String> list1=new ArrayList<String>();
list1.add("a");
list1.add("b");
// c is missing in the list
list1.add("d");
list1.add("e");
ListIterator<String> it=list1.listIterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
    if(it.next().equals("b")){
        // add c in the list after b
        it.add("c");
    }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list1.toArray(new String[]{})));
```

output:

```
[a, b, c, d, e]
```

Comment: I have added sample code as well to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

When looping through an ArrayList if you want to make any modifications to it, you must then loop via iterator, as the regular for loop won't help you then, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18448699/1638739).

```
Iterator<String> iter = myArrayList.iterator();

while (iter.hasNext()) {
    String str = iter.next();

    if (someCondition)
        iter.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The **only** way you're allowed to add to an `ArrayList` while you're looping over it is by using an iterator:

```
ListIterator<String> iterator = bultosHijos.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String str = iterator.next();
    // now if we want to...
    iterator.add("some other string");
}
```

The iterator also has a `.remove()`, and a `.set()` for editing an element.

There is no `.addAll()` on a `ListIterator`, so if you want to add lots of elements, you have to create your own loop and add them one by one:

```
for (String s: bultosNietos)
    iterator.add(s);
```

Any other way of modifying the list will give a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Concurent package. Use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html