# why there is no add method in Iterator interface

Tags: java, collections, iterator

In `Iterator` Sun added the remove method to remove the last accessed element of the collection. Why there is no add method to add a new element to the collection? What kind of side-effects it may have to the collection or iterator?

Comment: I think you have a duplication:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/993025/java-adding-elements-to-a-collection-during-iteration

Comment: @mihaisimi -- no, this is really a different question.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Still coobird provided a good answer to this on that thread.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The sole purpose of an Iterator is to enumerate through a collection. All collections contain the `add()` method to serve your purpose. There would be no point in adding to an Iterator because the collection may or may not be ordered (in the case of a `HashSet`).

**EDIT:** While working on another problem, I came up with another reason that `Iterator` lacks an `add()` method. Looking under the hood of [`ArrayList`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList) (line 111), and [`HashMap`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap) (line 149), we see that the implementation is just a few methods surrounding an array of objects. Now we consider how arrays are treated in memory.

[image: zero-based array indexes]

This is an array of 5 elements. However, there are six indices. The letter "a" in this array is listed as element 0 because in order to read it, left to right like a computer does, you have to start at index 0. Now, if we are iterating through this array (yes, collection, but it boils down to an array), we will start at index 0 and continue to index 1. At this point in the Iterator, we want to call `add("f");`. At this point, let's compare the implications of `add()` and `remove()`. `remove()` would leave a space in the array, which is easy to jump over, because we can immediately recognize that it isn't a member. On the other hand, `add()` would put a new element in which wasn't there before. This will affect the length of the array that we're iterating through. What happens when we get to that last element? Can we even guarantee that it is there (that is, that the array hasn't exceeded [the maximum size](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.0MAX_ARRAY_SIZE))?

All in all, the arguments one way or another both have valid points, but the bottom line is that the behavior of an `add()` method is not well defined in all cases. Sun had to make a choice where to limit functionality, and they chose not to include this method.

Comment: "because the collection may or may not be ordered" - do you please elaborate it a little. Thanks

Comment: I got your statement :-) . Thanks

Comment: A HashSet gives no guarantee for the order of its members. If you are iterating through it to try to find a point at which to insert a value, you've just defeated the point of an Iterator.

Comment: But then there wouldn't be a point in removing from an `Iterator` either. Yet `remove()` exists to make it (optionally) possible to remove elements without invalidating the `Iterator`. Shouldn't `add(E)` exist to make it possible to add elements without invalidating the `Iterator`? Of course you can add elements to the `Iterable` after the iteration. But the same goes for removal of elements. I think `Iterator` has a `remove()` method because generally it's efficient, easy to implement and defined clearly in contrast to `add(T)`.

Comment: @Robert It's a shaky argument, I admit, but I agree with your last sentence. As jontro links in his (second) answer, the design FAQ doesn't even give a good explanation. I believe a `remove()` method has more of a place in an `Iterator` than an `add(T)` method. The bottom line is that, for some reason, Sun chose to limit an `Iterator`'s capabilities at that particular point.

Comment: But then ListIterator has add method. Then these points goes same for listiterator as well

Answer (score 13):

Okay, here we go:

The answer is clearly stated in the design faq:

Why don't you provide an Iterator.add method?

The semantics are unclear, given that the contract for Iterator makes no guarantees about the order of iteration. Note, however, that ListIterator does provide an add operation, as it does guarantee the order of the iteration.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/collections/designfaq.html#10

Comment: Sorry for being late to answer. But for example LinkedHashSet does maintain insertion order. Why didn't they make Iterator for it then? `Add()` method in that case would work fine, right?

Comment: @Stefan read this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26277042/no-listiterator-in-linkedhashmap-and-linkedhashset which covers that case

Answer (score 5):

If you are working on a list you could use [ListIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) which provides both add and remove operations.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question actually. But yes, `Iterator` doesn't implement `add` because it's not `ListIterator`.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add one more point.

```java
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
arrayList.add("aa");
arrayList.add("ab");
Iterator<String> iterator = arrayList.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String string = (String) iterator.next();
}
```

Here the iterator takes max to max 2 iterations to complete it's iteration.
So the iterator will take a definite time to complete it's iteration in N time.

But what if we add the `add()` method:

```java
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String string = (String) iterator.next();
    iterator.add("adding this data means iterator will always have next 
                    element.")
}
```

So adding `add()` in the iterator will have a chance to run an infinite loop.
And simply we use iterator to traverse over the element, to not get in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Iterator have a pointer to the next element only. where as ListIterator have pointers to the previous element also(remember, it can traverse backwards).

Answer (score 1):

Because ListIterator maintains the insertion order and so you can get to a point where you want to add. Iterator doesn't care about order and so what if it adds the object in past values while iterating than that would be a disaster. That's the reason iterator is only given remove() method because you have a particular object and place from where to remove.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of any theoretical reason why `add()` could not have been included in `Iterator`. Just as the `Iterator` can allow for elements being removed from the collection through itself, it could be designed to handle elements being added in the same way.

But I will say that in all my years of programming in Java -- over 15! -- I have never wanted an `Iterator.add()` method. So I suspect it's simply not all that useful.