# ConcurrentModificationException In a Java BO

Tags: java, exception

I am getting a java.util.ConcurrentModificationException in this code and can't seem to understand why, or fix it.

In the BO I have this (privileges is an arraylist inside the BO)

```
public void setPrivilegename(String privilegename) {
    this.privileges.add(privilegename); 
}

List<PrivilegeObjectBO> arraylist = new ArrayList<PrivilegeObjectBO>();if (rs != null)              {
    while (rs.next()) {        
        for (BO bo : arraylist) {
            if (bo.getRolepkey()==rs.getInt("ROLE_PKEY")) {                         
                bo.setPrivilegename(rs.getString("SP.NAME"));

            }else{
                BO newobj = new BO();
                newobj.setRolepriviledgepkey(rs.getInt("PRIVILEGE_PKEY"));
                newobj.setProticolpkey(protocol);                
                newobj.setPrivilegename(rs.getString("SP.NAME"));
                newobj.setRolepkey(rs.getInt("SRP.ROLE_PKEY"));
                arraylist.add(newobj);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java, you will always get a ConcurrentModificationException when you modify the Collection while you are iterating over it.

Possible solution: use a temporary Collection for added or deleted items, and add or delete those items after the iteration is done.

Comment: you will always get that exception if you modify the collection

Answer (score 3):

As per [ArrayList javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

> The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator
>   methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any
>   time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the
>   iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a
>   ConcurrentModificationException.

```
for (BO bo : arraylist)
```

Above for-each loop gets Iterator for the list and

```
  arraylist.add(newobj);
```

You are trying to modify the list without using iterators own methods, which results in `ConcurrentModificationException`

Here is [SO discussion on possible solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624220/java-adding-elements-to-list-while-iterating-over-it).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot iterate over `ArrayList` and add elements to it at the same time with foreach.

Use iterator, like this:

```
Iterator<PrivilegeObjectBO> iterator = arraylist.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can take a look at `Collections.synchronizedList(List<?>)` static method.
It should return a thread safe `List` from the List object given, and you should not get the exception anymore.
Otherwise, you could try (if applicable) to set the method that accesses to the list synchronized, by adding the keyword `synchronized` in the method declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Others have already pointed out that `add`-ing to an `ArrayList` while iterating over it is disallowed.

But to solve your problem anyway, it *looks like* you need to iterate over the entire list before attempting to `add` to it, because it your loop appears to be checking to see if anything in the list matches your row to avoid duplicates.  In this case you don't *want* to add to the list while iterating over it because you don't know whether the list has a duplicate until the end.

So just iterate through and check to see if a match is found:

```
List<PrivilegeObjectBO> arraylist = new ArrayList<PrivilegeObjectBO>();
if (rs != null) {
    while (rs.next()) {

        boolean found = false;
        for (BO bo : arraylist) {
             if (bo.getRolepkey() == rs.getInt("ROLE_PKEY")) {      
                 bo.setPrivilegename(rs.getString("SP.NAME"));
                 found = true;
             }
        }

        if (!found) {
            BO newobj = new BO();
            newobj.setRolepriviledgepkey(rs.getInt("PRIVILEGE_PKEY"));
            newobj.setProticolpkey(protocol);                
            newobj.setPrivilegename(rs.getString("SP.NAME"));
            newobj.setRolepkey(rs.getInt("SRP.ROLE_PKEY"));
            arraylist.add(newobj);
        }
    }
}
```

Unless you really do want to add a new `BO` for every non-matching `BO` already in the list...