# Java - ConcurrentModificationException when adding to a list

Tags: java

I'm trying to add an item to a list of lists. `partitions` is a `LinkedList` of lists of `Strings`. I'm trying to add an item to the begining of one of the partitions in the list of partitions, but I'm getting a `ConcurrentModificationException`, even though I'm using a copy of the list called `partitionsCopy`.

Is there any way to do this? All I can find are examples on how to remove items or add items using `ListIterator`, but I can't add an item at a specific position with `ListIterator`

```
int index = 0;
for (List<String<?>> partition : partitions) {
    if (index > 0) {
        partitionsCopy.get( index ).add(0, lastPartition.get(lastPartition.size() - 1));
    }
    lastPartition = partition;
    index++;
}
```

partitionsCopy looks like this

```
List<List<String<?>>> partitionsCopy = new LinkedList<List<String<?>>>( );
partitionsCopy.addAll( partitions );
```

Here's what I came up with from jtahlborn's answer.

```
  for ( List<String<?>> partition : partitions ) {
    List<String<?>> list = new ArrayList<String<?>>( );
    list.addAll( partition );
    partitionsCopy.add( list );
  }
```

Comment: Is partitionsCopy a deep copy?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/993025/java-adding-elements-to-a-collection-during-iteration

Comment: Is `partitionsCopy` really a copy of the `List`, rather than just another reference to the same `List`?  Where do you initialize that variable?

Comment: Why does string have a generic argument on it in your code? Is it not a normal java.lang.String? Also, how is `lastPartition` declared? Looks to me like it's probably a reference to the same list as `partitions`, which would cause the issue.

Comment: Are any other threads modifying the outer or inner lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem isn't with `partitionsCopy`, it's with whatever is *in* `partitionsCopy` (the nested List), as that is the List that you are *actually* modifying.  When you copy `partitions` into `partitionsCopy`, you are only copying the references to the nested Lists.  You are *not* copying the nested Lists themselves.