# how to convert list of strings into arraylist and call it individually?

Tags: java, date, arraylist, while-loop

i have a list of strings which is from a loop statement and i don't know how to make  it an ArrayList then call the strings individually. here is the while statement :

```
try {
    toDate=format.parse(str4);
    java.util.Date newValue= new SimpleDateFormat(OLD_FORMAT).parse(str4);
    String newValue2 = new SimpleDateFormat(NEW_FORMAT).format(newValue);
    // System.out.println(newValue2);
} catch (ParseException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}


//change the format of toDate 
try {
    newDateString=format.parse(str5);
    java.util.Date newqwe = new SimpleDateFormat(OLD_FORMAT).parse(str5);
    String newqwe2=new SimpleDateFormat (NEW_FORMAT).format(newqwe);
    //System.out.println(newqwe2);
} catch (ParseException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

//get the days between two dates then print it 
Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal2.setTime(toDate);
while (cal2.getTime().before(newDateString)) {
    cal2.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    String datelist=(format.format(cal2.getTime()));
```

str4 is from a label which is a date same as str5, when a button is clicked the strings from the loop statement will be like this:

```
2013-05-03
2013-05-04
2013-05-05
2013-05-05
2013-05-06
2013-05-07
2013-05-08
2013-05-09
2013-05-10
2013-05-11
2013-05-12
2013-05-13
2013-05-14
2013-05-15
2013-05-16
2013-05-17
```

Comment: Try something on your own. Ask only when you got stuck.

Comment: well basically I'm already stuck this is just a part of my work... if you know please tell me. i have spend 2 days looking for answers :D

Answer (score 2):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

 list.add("2013-05-03");
 list.add("2013-05-04");
 ........etc

 for(String str:list)
  System.out.prinltn(str); // prints all the strings in list


System.out.println(list.get(index)); // prints string at specified index
```

Comment: this will print the whole list, what if i want to print one string from the list of strings. if i will do this i can easily print datelist instead.

Comment: `System.out.println(list.get(index));` where *index* is the position of the String you would like to print.

Comment: i cant add the strings individually because they are from a while loop, is there a way I can add then while running the loop?  the strings from the while statement is not constant they change depending on the dates from str4 and str5.

Comment: you can use this code in while loop by declaring list out side loop

Comment: @JohnPaulMagat you should at least try using `List<String> ls = new ArrayList<String>();` and then come with something else. From your post, looks like you tried nothing and are in *gimme the codez* mode.

Comment: @PSR: is this right? System.out.println(list.get(2)); which will print the third string from the list of strings right?

Comment: @PSR well it didn't work. only the first string from the list is printed then many red stuff appears (error). which looks like this                     2013-05-16
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 15, Size: 1
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
 at q$8$1.actionPerformed(q.java:938)

Comment: this is related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/993025/java-adding-elements-to-a-collection-during-iteration