# add an item into specific index in list while iterating over it

Tags: java

I have string ArrayList that reads a script, and I'm iterating over it. 
My issue is that when I find an item that begins whit "WHEN" I have to fetch the next items until the next "WHEN" and add a new item "END WHEN" just before it and te same goes for "END CASE".
it's working with "END CASE" but for "WHEN" it shows the following error.

[given error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCWR6.png)

```
List<String> lines = ss.readFile("test.sql");
    String line = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
        line = lines.get(i);

        if (line != null) {
            line = lines.get(i).trim();

            if(line.matches("CASE (.*)") )
             {
                String next = null;
                for(int j=i+2;j<lines.size();j++)
                {
                    next = lines.get(j);
                    if(next!=null && next.trim().matches("WHEN (.*)"))
                    {                           
                        lines.add(j,"# END WHEN");
                    }   
                    else if(next!=null && next.trim().matches("END CASE(.*)") )
                    {
                        lines.add(j,"# END WHEN");
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
             }
}
    }
```

>

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
at java.util.ArrayList.grow(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
at java.util.ArrayList.ensureExplicitCapacity(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
at java.util.ArrayList.add(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
at com.sopra.banking.UploadApplication.initApplication(UploadApplication.java:52) [classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:365) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:308) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:135) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:424) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1700) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$162/993646570.getObject(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
```

Comment: Add you code and the error, not images of your code.

Comment: and an input example (example of lines)

Comment: your lines are changing on size, better use an iterator to add/remove

Comment: from what I see you're trying to add lines to the same collection your iterating on (`lines`). Check [adding elements to a collection during iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993025/adding-elements-to-a-collection-during-iteration)

Comment: What is the size of your file and what is the heapsize you are using?

Comment: the size of my file is almost 9 ko, but can that be an issue?