# Why is it not possible to add values to my ArrayList in java after creating an object of iterator

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I am learning about collection classes in Java. I created an ArrayList and added some values to it.

```
package LearningJava;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Java{

    public static void  main(String args[]) {

        Collection values = new ArrayList();
        values.add(2);
        values.add(3);
        values.add(5);
        values.add(4);

        Iterator itr = values.iterator();
        for(int i = 0 ; i<values.size();i++) {
            System.out.println(itr.next());
        }
    }
}
```

I also iterated through this ArrayList.

If I add values after creating, the object of iterator throws an exception.

```
package LearningJava;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Java{

    public static void  main(String args[]) {

        Collection values = new ArrayList();
        values.add(2);
        values.add(3);
        values.add(5);
    
        Iterator itr = values.iterator();
        values.add(4);
    
        for(int i = 0 ; i<values.size();i++) {
            System.out.println(itr.next());
        }
    }
}
```

It throws a `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`. Why can't I add values after creating the object of iterator?

It is only throwing this exception in case of Iterator interface. When I create the object of other classes, it does not throw any exception.

```
package LearningJava;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Java{

    public static void  main(String args[]) {

        Collection values = new ArrayList();
        values.add(2);
        values.add(3);
        values.add(5);
    
         // creating the object of scanner instead of iterator's.
        Scanner input  = new Scanner(System.in);

        values.add(4);

        Iterator itr = values.iterator();
        for(int i = 0 ; i<values.size();i++) {
            System.out.println(itr.next());
        }
    }
}
```

Here it is not showing any errors. Why is this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding elements to a collection during iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993025/adding-elements-to-a-collection-during-iteration)

Comment: Note that (at least part of) the state that tracks if the source collection has been concurrently structrually modified is held by the `Iterator` instance (at least as currently implemented). If the source collection is structurally modified _after_ the `Iterator` has been created, then it's possible the `Iterator` will be out-of-date or otherwise "damaged", and so it throws the error. And also note that if you were to create an `Iterator`, structurally modify the collection, and then create a **new** `Iterator` and use that **new** `Iterator` in your loop, then the error would not be thrown.

Comment: When you use an iterator, you should use `hasNext()` instead of a counter, e.g. `for(Iterator itr = values.iterator(); itr.hasNext(); ) { System.out.println(itr.next()); }` Which is equivalent to `for(Object obj: values) { System.out.println(obj); }` When you want to add elements while an iterator exist, you have to use a `ListIterator` and add elements through the iterator.

Answer (score 5):

This behaviour is documented in the `ArrayList`'s [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html):

> The iterators returned by this class's `iterator` and `listIterator` methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own `remove` or `add` methods, the iterator will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Adding an element counts as modifying the list "structurally", and note the wording "after the iterator is created".

The modification is detected when you start iterating over the list using `next`, which is where the exception is thrown.

See also [Why is a ConcurrentModificationException thrown and how to debug it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/602636/5133585) for details about what a `ConcurrentModificationException` is, though that question doesn't specifically address the case where you modify the collection immediately after creating the iterator, without calling `next`.